# Post a value from Jquery to variable PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to post a value when I click the button,
so when I click `<a id="link1"> Page Home </a>`, it will send the value to custom variable `php`

ex:

```
<?php
$linkredirect = ''; //it will send to php include
?>
<ul>
    <li><a id="link1"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a id="link2"> Profile </a></li>
    <li><a id="link3"> Contact </a></li>
</ul>

<?php include ($linkredirect); ?>
as far as I know the jquery:
$(function() {
    $('#link').click(function() {
        $.post($linkredirect)
        // in this column that I do not know 

    });
});
```

Can you help me to fill These variables change with a click?.

the details that I want is, the nav is fixed but the attr body will be change with the `<?php include();?>`

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Send what? You've got half an AJAX setup but it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: $linkredirect is php variable. you can not use it directly in javascrip or jquery.

Comment: when the  `<li><a id="link1 or 2 or 3"></a></li>`  clicked. it will send a value from variable that has been prepared. so the variable for `$link1 = 'home.php';` . value of that variable will send to `$linkredirect = ''` . and the `$linkredirect' will send to `<?php include ($linkredirect);?>`

Comment: What's the name of your page?

Comment: index.php, maybe the name is not the problem - @MackProgramsAlot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$page_num = isset($_GET['pageNum']) ? $_GET['pageNum'] : NULL;
if (!is_null($page_num)) {
    $linkredirect = NULL;
    switch ($page_num) {
        case 1:
            $linkredirect = 'home.php';
            break;
        case 2:
            $linkredirect = 'profile.php';
            break;
        case 3:
            $linkredirect = 'contact.php';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="?pageNum=1"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="?pageNum=2"> Profile </a></li>
    <li><a href="?pageNum=3"> Contact </a></li>
</ul>
<?php
    if (!is_null($linkredirect)) {
        include($linkredirect );
    }
?>
```

Comment: hey it's work, does the page is reload when clicked attr a?

Comment: Yes. 'Href' is the attribute. 'A' is the element.

Comment: is there any way to load pages without refresh?